# Excel multilevel array formula with partial string matches to sum resultant cells

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I've been trying to sort this for over a day now without much luck. I have successfully used SUMIFS, INDEX, MATCH, COUNTIF, "--" etc array functions previously and am not a novice, but also not an expert on these. I can't seem to weave these together correctly, and likely on an altogether incorrect path.

Basically, I am trying to aggregate data from multiple spreadsheets, requiring a mapping of various items (rows) into a canonical form for summing.

The image here shows a representative, but simplified version of my quest. Each "region" on this example spreadsheet (Final..., Mapping, DataSet1, DataSet2) is actually in different spreadsheets, and there are several sheets with 50-150 rows in each xlsx.

[image: The image here shows a representative, but simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve. As mentioned, each "region" (Final..., Mapping, DataSet1, DataSet2) is actually in different spreadsheets, and there are several sheets in each xlsx.]

Note that the names in Column B are quite arbitrary (meaning not all P1's have an 'x' pattern, like shown here as x1, x2, etc. Do not rely on any pattern in the names, except the x, y , z in the Mapping table are substrings (case insensitive, trailing match) of the names in Column B in the DataSets.

And in the image, the Final Result Table (summed manually) is what I want to compute via(an array) formula: A single formula would be ideal (given I have many spreadsheets from which the monthly data is being pulled from, so I can't readily modify but can create an interim spreadsheet if required, so open to helper columns or helper rows).

Here's the process - For each name (B3-B5) in the Final Result Table, I want to sum the name from it's components as follows:

1. Lookup all the matches in the Mapping Table (so for P1, the formula =IF($C$10:$C$15=$B3, $B$10:$B$15,"") gives {"x1";"";"";"x2";"";"x3"}.
2. I then want to search each of x1, x2, and x3 in B19:B26 to get rows 21, 22, 24, 25, 26 in DataSet1 and B31:B35 to get row 32 in DataSet2, to then add up the Jan totals into C3. (Effectively,
   C3=C21+C22+C24+C25+C26+C32). Same for P2 and P3, and thru Feb, Mar, ...

I am stuck on how to remove blank or 0 or Div0 or such "error rows" from the interim result in 2, and also need to use 2 arrays of different sizes (3 valid rows in example 2 above, ignoring blanks) to search many rows in DataSets. I tried SEARCH("*"&IF($C$10:$C$15=$B3, $B$10:$B$15,""), $B$19:$B$26) but get unexpected results. I have tried to replace text in the interim result {"x1";"";"";"x2";"";"x3"} with TRUE/FALSE, and 1/0, etc. to help with INDEX or MATCH, but am stymied by errors in downstream ("surrounding") formulas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without resorting to nasty (imo) CSE formulas.

```
=  SUMPRODUCT($C$19:$F$26*(COUNTIFS($B$10:$B$15, RIGHT($B$19:$B$26,2),$C$10:$C$15,$B3)>0)*($C$18:$F$18=C$2))
   +
   SUMPRODUCT($C$31:$F$35*(COUNTIFS($B$10:$B$15, RIGHT($B$31:$B$35,2),$C$10:$C$15,$B3)>0)*($C$30:$F$30=C$2))
```

There is one `SUMPRODUCT` for each data set. If possible, it would be better to put all your data sets into a single table with a column identify which data set it is a part of.

[image]

The way it works is to takes each values in your data set and multiplies it by whether the 2 right most character appear in your mapping table for that P code, multiplied by whether the value is in the correct month. So it returns 0 if either of those conditions are false. Then returns the sum.

**UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO OP COMMENTS**

If, the X,Y, Z codes are not always 2 digits but the first part is ALWAYS 8 digits, you can easily amend the:

```
RIGHT($B$19:$B$26,2)
```

to be:

```
RIGHT($B$19:$B$26,LEN($B$19:$B$26)-8)
```

Making the formula for the first data set:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$19:$F$26*(COUNTIFS($B$10:$B$15, RIGHT($B$19:$B$26,LEN($B$19:$B$26)-8),$C$10:$C$15,$B3)>0)*($C$18:$F$18=C$2))
```

And you can amend for other data sets and simply add them together.

Comment: Both solutions work on the test spreadsheet. I will be working on the main set soon. But greatly appreciate it. Will revert back in case of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Nice challenge! Are you willing to drop all your tables (DataSet1, DataSet2...) into one spreadsheet, so that we can refer just one single range for each month?

Here's one solution (hopefully a good starting point) - array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(TRANSPOSE(IF($B3=$C$10:$C$15,$B$10:$B$15,""))=RIGHT($B$18:$B$36,2),C$18:C$36,0),0))`

[image]

Comment: Awesome, both you Justyna dn Gravitate. And both quite simple. Can't wait to try it (will i a few hours). But 2 "issues" to note:wrt to RIGHT, the x/y/z are not 2 chars and in fact variable length, BUT the prefix (100-, etc) are exactly 8 chars in the original data. Also, not practical to merge all data into a single xls or "table" as Gravitate suggested. BUT I am OK putting different references to files in each cell of the formula (and the months are for 2018 and 2019 so not an inordinately large number of columns).

Comment: Did not mean to trivialize the response by saying "simple". Elegant may be a better word here. In any case, hope to try these soon.

Comment: Hey @retd111 sorry for a small delay, Xmas period can be quite engaging! :)  for RIGHT I think you can try using `RIGHT($B$18:$B$36,LEN($B$18:$B$36)-9)` instead of `RIGHT($B$18:$B$36,2)` (9 = prefix of 8 char plus "-" symbol). I wonder if the solution proved useful (fingers crossed!).

Comment: The formula works great. And yes, I used the RIGHT adjustments already. Many thanx. One quirk is that I have anywhere from 2-4 disjoint ranges so have that many SUMPRODUCTS (eg. SP() + SP() + SP ()), which is a lot of repetition. However, I am not complaining. Both formulas are great.